# Erro rake db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Boa tarde,

estou utilizando um programa de outra pessoa desenvolvido em Ruby on Rails e após dar `bundle install` na pasta do projeto e instalar todas as `gems`, tentei criar o banco de dados através dos comandos:

`rake db:create` e `rake db:migrate`

Porém está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

> Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 10.4.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.3.1. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.

Procurei alguma solução, porém não consegui resolver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece porque você está usando a versão rake 10.4.2 e o sistema está pedindo a versão 10.3.1.

**Você tem 2 opções:**

**1)** Desinstalar a gem atual e instalar a versão que o programa está pedindo.

- abra o cmd e navegue até o diretório do seu projeto
- digite o comando: `gem uninstall rake -v 10.4.2`
- digite o comando: `gem install rake -v 10.3.1`

**2)** Alterar os arquivos Gemfile do seu projeto, onde está especificando a versão do rake para 10.3.1 e mudar para 10.4.2

Depois de uma dessas duas opções execute `bundle install` para que as gems possam ser atualizadas, conforme a nova versão do rake.
Em seguida, teste novamente o procedimento que deseja.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Resolveu o problema.